# @variable args don't make sense

Tags: business-objects

I am implementing a feature similar to BO's @variable and something doesn't make sense to me.

Why does BO Support 2 ways of specifying @variable:

- @variable(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)
- @variable('BOUSER')

Note the single quotes in the 2nd one above. Why didn't they just make it, without the quotes:
- @variable(BOUSER)

I am wondering if I should support var names within quotes or without (or both like above which doesn't make sense).

Thanks

Comment: Only the second syntax is valid.

Comment: Not quite true. See this, the examples show both the above syntax: http://noreports.com/variable-and-variable-functions-in-business-objects/

Comment: Well, Praveen, that page is wrong.  Try both syntaxes and get back to me.

Comment: Joe is right: we always use the notation @VARIABLE('BOUSER')